# How do you make a WinXP bootable USB drive?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, boot, usb, operating-system

**How do you make a WinXP bootable USB drive?**

I've seen a bunch of instruction here on ServerFault but they are specific to Vista or Linux, so again - I'm using **WinXP**. I've also tried unetbootin, but that doesn't work with Windows

Answer (score 3):

Use BartPE to make a minimal environment you can boot from USB media, and from there you can prepare your windows installation and run the appropriate installer.

http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/

Once you have configured your BartPE image, and sent it to your USB drive. Go ahead and reboot and issue the following command:

```
D:\i386\winnt32.exe /syspart:C: /tempdrive:C: /makelocalsource
```

Where D: is your USB drive, and C: is the hard drive you want to install to. Just walk through the various prompts etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried that, but a google search pulled up this pre-done image for a bootable xp image for USB sticks:
http://keznews.com/2407_Windows_XP_USB_Stick_Edition

Comment: That's for creating a WinXP recovery bootup - not the operating system install

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://serverfault.com/questions/24798/how-to-boot-from-usb-using-iso-image-closed, which was closed today but has additional information on how to get an XP image onto a USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember that not all motherboards will boot off the USB chain.  You might want to verify that yours does before you put too much energy into the project.